# Adding a new column into sqlite produces an error: Exception while computing database live data

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room

I have this data class, I added a new value into it `requirePolice`

```
@Entity
data class Crime(@PrimaryKey val id : UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),
                 var title: String ="",
                 var date: Date = Date(),
                 var isSolved: Boolean = false,
                 var requirePolice : Boolean = false, <--- this is the new value
                 var suspect: String = ""){

    //designating a picture location p.317
    val photoFileName
        get() = "IMG_$id.jpg"
}
```

I upgraded the data base from 2 to 3 to include it in the SQLite table, i kept the previous upgrade code also there

```
@Database(entities = [Crime::class], version = 3)
@TypeConverters(CrimeTypeConverters::class) 
abstract class CrimeDatabase: RoomDatabase(){

    abstract fun crimeDao() : CrimeDao

}

val migration_1_2 = object : Migration(1,2){
    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Crime ADD COLUMN suspect TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT ''")
    }
}

val migration_2_3 = object : Migration(2,3){
    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Crime ADD COLUMN requirePolice TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT ''")
    }
}
```

I included the upgrade into the Repository this way

```
private const val DATABASE_NAME = "crime-database"

class CrimeRepository private constructor(context: Context){

    private val database: CrimeDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(
        context.applicationContext,
        CrimeDatabase::class.java,
        DATABASE_NAME
    ).addMigrations(migration_1_2)
     .addMigrations(migration_2_3)//adding latest migration 
     .build()
...
```

I keep getting this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: arch_disk_io_0
    Process: com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent, PID: 22566
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while computing database live data.
        at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$1.run(RoomTrackingLiveData.java:92)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle: Crime(com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.Crime).
     Expected:
    TableInfo{name='Crime', columns={date=Column{name='date', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, requirePolice=Column{name='requirePolice', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id=Column{name='id', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, suspect=Column{name='suspect', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, title=Column{name='title', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, isSolved=Column{name='isSolved', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
     Found:
    TableInfo{name='Crime', columns={date=Column{name='date', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, requirePolice=Column{name='requirePolice', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue=''''}, isSolved=Column{name='isSolved', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id=Column{name='id', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, suspect=Column{name='suspect', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, title=Column{name='title', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
        at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade(RoomOpenHelper.java:103)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onUpgrade(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:177)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:416)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:316)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:145)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:731)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:508)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:551)
        at androidx.room.util.DBUtil.query(DBUtil.java:83)
        at com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.database.CrimeDao_Impl$3.call(CrimeDao_Impl.java:158)
        at com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.database.CrimeDao_Impl$3.call(CrimeDao_Impl.java:155)
        at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$1.run(RoomTrackingLiveData.java:90)
            ... 3 more
```

why it gave me this error?
how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the failure is explained in :-

```
Expected:
    TableInfo{name='Crime', columns={date=Column{name='date', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, requirePolice=Column{name='requirePolice', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id=Column{name='id', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, suspect=Column{name='suspect', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, title=Column{name='title', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, isSolved=Column{name='isSolved', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
     Found:
    TableInfo{name='Crime', columns={date=Column{name='date', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, requirePolice=Column{name='requirePolice', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue=''''}, isSolved=Column{name='isSolved', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id=Column{name='id', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, suspect=Column{name='suspect', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, title=Column{name='title', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

More specifically the expected (what the Entity EXPECTS) is :-

```
requirePolice=Column{name='requirePolice', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}
```

Whilst the table (what was FOUND) has been altered to be :-

```
requirePolice=Column{name='requirePolice', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue=''''}
```

The main difference is that instead of a column type of INTEGER (Boolean equates to INTEGER) the ALTER has set the column type to TEXT.

- i.e. EXPECTED **INTEGER** (Boolean) FOUND **TEXT** (String)

As such you need to use :-

```
val migration_2_3 = object : Migration(2,3){
override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
    database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Crime ADD COLUMN requirePolice INTEGER NOT NULL")
}
```

OR change the Entity to be ***(probably not what you want)***:-

```
@Entity
data class Crime(@PrimaryKey val id : UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),
                 var title: String ="",
                 var date: Date = Date(),
                 var isSolved: Boolean = false,
                 var requirePolice : String = "", <--- this is the new value
                 var suspect: String = ""){

    //designating a picture location p.317
    val photoFileName
        get() = "IMG_$id.jpg"
}
```

- It is likely that it is the ALTER statement that you want to change rather than the Entity.

**How to avoid such EXPECTED/FOUND discrepancies - aka let Room do the work for you**

You can actually ascertain what is EXPECTED by creating/changing the Entity and then compiling <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>, after a successful compile the underlying java is generated and this actually contains the SQL to create the table(s).

You can view the SQL by selecting Android View, locating the java (generated) folder, expanding it and then expanding the folders and then locating the class that is named the same as your @Database class suffixed with _Impl (**CrimeDatabase_Impl** in your case) in the class there will be a **createAllTables** method, this contains the EXPECTED SQL for all the tables you can then extract/copy the SQL for the definition(s) of the changed column(s) and use this in the ALTER statement (if adding a new Entity then you also have the SQL for the entire table).

- Note as per the warning DO NOT CHANGE anything in the class.

Here's an example of the above (not for your project though) :-
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql light db, then you have to migrate the db in this way,

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    
    if (oldVersion < 4) {
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_NOTIFICATION + " ADD COLUMN " + COLUMN_DEEP_LINK + " TEXT ");
    }
}
```

Comment: how is that in Kotlin?

Comment: @SaherAl-Sous can you please update your question with the class where you are creating your tables?

Comment: you mean the location of the db? it is on the emulator... i added the location inside the gradle...

kapt {
    arguments {
        arg("room.schemaLocation", "$projectDir/schemas/")
    }
}

Comment: you are using roomDb not sql lite.

Comment: room uses sqlite under the hood... maybe i should update the tags then...